# Custom flutter navigation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation, flutter-cupertino

I am using CupertinoPageRoute for their navigation animation and I want to customize it a bit. Page
I am going to(Page2) will slide from right and when I pop that page(Go back to Page1) it will slide in opposite direction(from left) that's default. I want my pop to slide in the same direction (from right). Like PageView but I'm navigating only between two pages. Green arrow show's direction I want.
Is there a way?[image: green Is what I want]

I tried building my custom navigation animation with PageRouteBuilder but could not do anything useful I don't want to push page1 on top of page2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition for page transition in any direction you want